# 410 Gone [IP: 2606:4700:20::681a:d05 443] when trying to run sudo apt update

Tags: kali-linux, postgresql, konsole

I have been trying to fix an error when running docker and as a result want to update my kali version, however i receive this when running sudo apt update

```
    E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb/dists/any/InRelease  410  Gone [IP: 2606:4700:20::681a:d05 443]
E: The repository 'https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb any InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried running sudo apt update --allow-unauthenticated as well as --allow-insecure-repositories So far, nothing at all as helped. This error is being spread across essentially every download, I cannot use PSQL anymore(this was my docker issue initially). Losing my mind over this. Any ideas? So far everything I have found online isn't helping.

Answer (score 3):

A 410 error means that the repository is no longer available, and indeed [visiting it](https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb/dists/any/InRelease) shows

> Error: this repository is depreciated by the developer. Please see: https://mirror.mwt.me/shiftkey-desktop/

You should remove the repository from your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Type this command in your terminal: `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Now add `#` in the beginning of every line.

Now add this line `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware`, note that, you don't need to add `#` at the beginning of this line as `#` will comment it out and will not work.

Hit `CTRL+X`, type Y or y, and hit ENTER. Done!

Try updating your system now using `apt update` or `sudo apt update` if you are not a root user. If you still face any other issue, feel free to ask again.